# talend open studio supports janusgraph

Tags: talend, janusgraph

I am using JanusGraph as by graph db and would need to upload data to graph. I have found talend open source studio as one of the option to load bulk data. Would want to know if it does have connector for JanusGraph or no.

Thanks,
Atul.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Helpful resources to bulk load data into JanusGraph:

- https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/bulk-loading/#batch-loading
- https://nitinpoddar.medium.com/bulk-loading-data-into-janusgraph-ace7d146af05